# How to go to a specific line number in DataGrid via ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to create a popup that once you enter a line number into the textbox and click a 'Go' button, it will take you to that line number in the DataGrid.

My question is, how to goto a specific line number in DataGrid via the ViewModel?

Comment: is it possible to use a search filter instead?

Comment: I will be adding filters as another piece of functionality as well, also a plain old find function. They each have subtle differences which are of benefit. So I would like to focus on going to a line for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I opted for an attached property

```
class SearchProperties
{
    #region DialogResult

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemToScrollIntoViewProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ItemToScrollIntoView", typeof(int?), typeof(SearchBehaviours), new PropertyMetadata(default(int?), OnItemToScrollIntoViewChanged));

    private static void OnItemToScrollIntoViewChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dg = d as DataGrid;
        if (dg == null)
            return;

        if (dg.Items.Count < 1)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue == null)
            return;

        int? new_value = (int?)e.NewValue;
        if (new_value != null)
        {
            int nonNullValue = new_value.GetValueOrDefault() - 1;
            object item = dg.Items[nonNullValue];
            dg.SelectedIndex = nonNullValue;
            dg.ScrollIntoView(item);
        }
    }

    public static int? GetItemToScrollIntoView(DependencyObject dp)
    {
        if (dp == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("dp");

        return (int?)dp.GetValue(ItemToScrollIntoViewProperty);
    }

    public static void SetItemToScrollIntoView(DependencyObject dp, object value)
    {
        if (dp == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("dp");

        dp.SetValue(ItemToScrollIntoViewProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

In the View I bound the value to a ViewModel property upon entering a number into the textbox and clicking Ok, the Ok command sets SelectedGridItem to the number entered :

```
<DataGrid helpers:SearchProperties.ItemToScrollIntoView="{Binding SelectedGridItem}">
```

Answer (score 0):

the viewmodel has no relation to the line number of the datagrid. the viewmodel do not even know that the collection is bound to a datagrid. for me your case is just view related and you should do this in code behind. if you would search after a ID number in your collection items then a viewmodel make sense

Comment: what about doing this through just xaml? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are populating datagrid from viewmodel then you will have whole list with you in the ViewModel itself so if you selecting 99 row you cand do

```
private ObservableCollection<CollectionType> _ItemSource;

public ObservableCollection<CollectionType> ItemSource
{
  get
  {
       return _ItemSource;
  }
  set
  {
    if(_ItemSource!=value)
     {
        _ItemSource=value;
      OnPropertyChanged("ItemSource");
     }
  }
}
```

in you button command just take the row id (ex :99)

in your button command

```
SelectedGridItem = ItemSource.skip(97).take(1).firstorDefault;
```

this will select selected item to paticular row, if your selected item is working for you and mode is TwoWay.

Comment: Not Sure with the index may be 98 or 97 :P

Comment: thanks, this selects the row and is useful, however it doesn't take you to the row, which is what I'm looking for.